# Is there an Azure Service that allows users to log in and access Azure API Management services?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an API that allows users to upload and download files through HTML pages. I was considering more user-friendly ways for users to access the API, as inserting their subscription key through the URL to access the API leaves a lot of room for error. Is there an Azure service for users to log in to my API who have already made an account through Azure API Management Service?

I was considering Azure AD B2C, however I am not 100% sure if this is the solution.

Comment: Yes, You can make use of Azure AD B2C API connector to connect to your API and allow users to access it after they get an access token, Refer this MS Document -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow Another easy way is to authenticate your APIM service directly with Azure AD refer this blog here -https://mscloud.be/azure/Enable-AzureAD-for-APIM-portal/

Comment: Thank you, I will use Azure AD B2C then. I was previously unaware that Azure AD B2C API connector existed, so this is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this Post as it is accepted in comments for the community.

***You can make use of Azure AD B2C API connector as mentioned in this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to connect to your API and allow users to access it after they are authenticated and get access token.***

> [image]
>
> Additional documents to integrate Azure Ad B2C with APIM:-
>
> 1. [Authorize developer accounts by using Azure Active Directory B2C -
>    Azure API Management | Microsoft
>    Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c)
> 2. [Secure an Azure API Management API by using Azure Active Directory
>    B2C | Microsoft
>    Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga)
> 3. [How to integrate Azure Active Directory B2C into Azure API
>    Management Developer Portal - Microsoft Community
>    Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-integrate-azure-active-directory-b2c-into-azure-api/ba-p/2424805#:%7E:text=1%20Sign%20in%20to%20the%20Azure%20portal%20and,developer%20portal%2C%20second%20one%20used%20for%20legacy%20portal.)

Alternatively,  another easy way is to authenticate your APIM service directly with Azure AD refer this [blog](https://mscloud.be/azure/Enable-AzureAD-for-APIM-portal/) for more information.