# Is there an user-friendly way to authenticate users to my Azure API without having to pass a subscription key or token?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I currently have an API in Azure APIM that requires authentication through submitting a subscription key through the header/url of the API. One of my requirements is that I make the API as user-friendly as possible, as less tech-savvy individuals are going to use this API. I want to remove the need to input a subscription key, and rather just have the users sign in for user-friendliness.

I have not gained access yet through my company to create an Azure AD B2C tenant, however through research (and previously asking asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201087/is-there-an-azure-service-that-allows-users-to-log-in-and-access-azure-api-manag)) I thought that using Azure AD B2C would be my solution. From what I understand with B2C, users need to obtain a JWT token using their login information and use this token to authenticate themselves with the API. The issue is that it's still not very user-friendly for people who aren't used to dealing with keys and access tokens.

I was wondering if there was a way to authenticate users when they try to access my API without providing some sort of authorization token/key, with just a simple login system. Also if my understanding of Azure AD B2C is incorrect please let me know as I am still very inexperienced with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can remove the need to input a subscription key while calling an API in APIM as below**-

[image]

If you want to use any Product but don't want to use the subscription key authentication, then uncheck the subscription key option from that specific Product.

[image]

[image]

> **Automatically enable the user sign-in to the API management using Azure AD**

[image]

**Please note**, once the Azure AD provider is enabled, users in the specified Azure AD instance can access the API in the APIM using an Azure AD account. Refer this [github link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/api-management-howto-aad.md) for more details.

Comment: Does this work for users who access the API outside of APIM?

Comment: Yes, It will. In the same way as the subscription key authentication works while calling the API via Postman. You can check the GitHub link as well

Comment: I completed the steps you described, and although this does remove the need for a subscription key, it makes my API publicly accessible with no authentication required to access the API. Is there a method that requires authentication?

Comment: Check this link to know about the types of authentication are there in APIM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authentication-authorization-overview

Comment: Thank you for the link! I don't 100% understand the documentation so please correct me if I'm wrong, but under "OAuth flow" it states that a JWT token would be obtained by the client after they authenticate using their credentials, would this be automatically sent to the API or would the user have to provide the token to the API?

Comment: It can be automatically sent to API. You can enable it by APIM instance-->APIs-->Go to Settings View-->select OAuth 2.0 under user Authentication. For more information, please refer https://auth0.com/docs/customize/integrations/azure-api-management

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this so I wanted to run by you the general user flow; the API would redirect the user to a log in page when they try to access the API without signing in first, and then after signing in the user would be sent back to the API where the JWT token is automatically sent for authorization?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254209/discussion-between-ikhtesam-afrin-and-bowlingh23).